# Indicies or numpy array to tuple of integers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to get a tuple that contains the indicies of the minimum value in an numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array(([2,3,1],[5,4,6],[8,7,9]))
b=np.where(a==np.min(a))
print(b)
```

gives:

```
(array([0]),array([2]))
```

Attempting to map the result to a tuple:

```
c=map(tuple,b)
print(c)
```

gives:

```
[(0,), (2,)]
```

but what I want is:

```
(0,2)
```

Any suggestions other than np.where are perfectly acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with the `where` result?  `a[b]` gives you the minimum value, doesn't it?  `where` returns a tuple of arrays (equivalently lists) because 0,1 or more elements may satisfy it's truth condition.

Comment: The problem with where is, as you said, it returns a tuple of arrays. My dictionary keys are tuples of ints (0,2). Unless I'm missing something, neither my_dict[b]=my_dict[(array([0]),array([2])) nor my_dict[c]=my_dict[[(0,), (2,)]] is the same as my_dict[(0,2)]

Comment: For use as dicitionary key, I'd do: `{tuple([i[0] for i in b]): a[b]}`.  `i.item()` would also work.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to get your desired result is

```
>>> np.unravel_index(a.argmin(), a.shape)
(0, 2)
```

The `argmin()` method finds the index of the minimum element in the flattened array in a single pass, and thus is more efficient than first finding the minimum and then using a linear search to find the index of the minimum.

As the second step, `np.unravel_index()` converts the scalar index into the flattened array back into an index tuple.  Note that the entries of the index tuple have the type `np.int64` rather than plain `int`.

Answer (score 2):

For a case when you would have multiple elements with the same `min` value, you might want to have a list of tuples. For such a case, you could  use `map` after column-stacking the rows and columns info obtained from `np.where`, like so -

```
map(tuple,np.column_stack(np.where(a==np.min(a))))
```

Sample run -

```
In [67]: a
Out[67]: 
array([[2, 2, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 3],
       [1, 0, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [68]: map(tuple,np.column_stack(np.where(a==np.min(a))))
Out[68]: [(0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 0)]
```